# Centering image in css for iphone

Tags: iphone, css, centering

Logo bere:  San-Francisco-Family-Photographer.com

On the iphone, the image won't center.

```
 .header-image #header #title-area {
    background: url("http://www.san-francisco-family-photographer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Joey-Chandler-Photographer-square.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    background-position: center;
    height: 130px!important;
    width: 180px!important;
}

.header-image #title-area, .header-image #title, .header-image #title a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could place it in a div and center it.

```
div#image {
    background: #282;
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```